# Reading text from image with Pytesseract gives bad path error

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, python-tesseract

Im trying to read text from image with pytesseract. Im using mac.
I have install pytesseract with pip.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread('slika1.png')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(text)
```

It gives me this error:

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your PATH. See README file for more information.
```

when I do this:

```
import importlib.util
print(importlib.util.find_spec('pytesseract'))
```

It prints:

```
ModuleSpec(name='pytesseract', loader=<_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f8a7837c160>, origin='/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytesseract/__init__.py', submodule_search_locations=['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytesseract'])
```

So what should I do, what am I doing wrong?
Is there any other way to read text from image?

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the module source file (as admin) and edit the path to the Tesseract exe file - set it with absolute path if needed. It should be a const in the top lines.

Something like this (on Win):

"C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py"
Set the path: ...
pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"D:\OCR\tesseract.exe"

https://github.com/Twenkid/ComputerVision_Pyimagesearch_OpenCV_Dlib_OCR-Tesseract-DL/blob/master/OCR_Tesseract/ocr.py